# Dataframe to dictionary, by rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [0.5, 0.75]})
```

and I want to create the dict:

```
{1 : 0.5 , 2 : 0.75 }
```

I tried `df.T.to_dict()` but still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `Series` and convert to `dictionary`:

```
print (df.set_index('col1')['col2'].to_dict())
{1: 0.5, 2: 0.75}
```

Or use `zip` with `dict`:

```
print (dict(zip(df['col1'], ['col2'])))
{1: 0.5, 2: 0.75}
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as zipping the columns together:

```
result = dict(zip(df.col1, df.col2))
print(result)
```

Or as an alternative:

```
result = dict(df[['col1', 'col2']].values)
print(result)
```